# SignalR Core sending messages but not receiving messages

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Im using SignalR Core and ASPNET Core 2.1 and in some computers messages are not received. Those computers can send msgs so I think something is blocking the incoming msgs.

I have already disabled the firewall but the problem persisted.

Any ideas what could be blocking them? Tomorrow I will use Fiddler to try to get more info.

Comment: Do you have log in browser console ?

Comment: It could be a proxy or a firewall blocking websocket, try to force long polling

Comment: No errors in the console. Firewall was disabled but the msgs were still blocked.

Comment: Did you configure the log level to Trace (= 0) ? `new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://somewhere').configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace).build();`

Comment: It was set to Information. I have just changed it to Trace and will do some tests and let you know asap.

Comment: I have just answered my own question but I wanted to thank you for checking this out @aguafrommars

Comment: Can you vote for my comments if that help ?

Comment: The extra logging information is useful but in this case that didn't help me to solve the issue. Anyway, I upvoted it because it might help others trying to solve an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that some messages were delivered and others not and the ones that were not working were the ones that were meant for specific users. It ended up being a case-sensitive issue :(

SignalR uses the user identifier that is saved, in my case, in a cookie and it is case sensitive. So, setting it always in lower case and lowercasing the user names fixed the issue.

**SignalR users and groups are case-sensitive.**